# Every Nash equilibrium is Subgame perfect Nash equilibrium

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, self-study, nash-equilibrium

> Every Nash equilibrium is Subgame perfect Nash equilibrium.

This statement is wrong. I show this by an counter example.

[image]

Is this example enough and good to disprove this statements?

Please share your ideas with me.

Thank you

Note: in the paper, there is typo.

(Out, price war) is not SPNE, but NE. (In, accomodate) is NE and SPNE. So, NE set covers all SPNE. But, SPNE set doesnt cover all NE

Comment: Are you asking if the negation of the statement "*all x are y*" is "*there is at least one y that is not x*"?

Comment: What does "(Out, price war) is only SPNE" mean here? If you mean it "is only a SPNE, but not a NE", then this is wrong, since every SPNE is a NE. If you mean it "is the only SPNE in this game", then you contradict the next sentence in which you claim that (in, accommodate) is also a SPNE...

Comment: @VARulle this is my inadequacy in language skill. So sorry. (Out, price war) is not SPNE, but NE. (In, accomodate) is NE and SPNE. So, NE set covers all SPNE. But, SPNE set doesnt cover all NE. Right now, my example is true?

Comment: Yes, apart from the "typo" in the lower right corner.

Comment: Many thanks:) @VARulle

Comment: Please link to other versions when crossposting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578612/every-nash-equilibrium-is-subgame-perfect-nash-equilibrium